# How can I remove an element from a list returned by a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to uncheck all checkboxes that have a specific class with the exception of the one just checked.

```
function PizzaToppings_OptionValueChanged(checkboxElement) {
    if ($(checkboxElement).attr("checked")) {
        if($(checkboxElement).hasClass('cheese_toppings'))
        {
            // This will uncheck all other "cheese_toppings" but I want the newly selected item "checkboxElement" to remain checked.
            $('input:checkbox.cheese_toppings').attr('checked', false);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will uncheck all "cheese_toppings" including the one just selected.  I don't want to then recheck the one just selected or the event will be recalled.

I thought the best solution would be to remove "checkboxElement" from the list returned by `$('input:checkbox.cheese_toppings')` and then set the `.attr('checked', false)` to that list. But I'm not sure how to remove checkboxElement from the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox.cheese_toppings').not(checkboxElement).attr('checked', false);
```

See the jQuery docs: [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Oooh, I didn't know about the input:type syntax...where is that documented?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Hi George, it came right out of the code for his question, but it ***is*** documented right here: http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ :)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Note that the `:checkbox` selector is jQuery only. It is not a CSS selector. There is a full list of jQuery selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Also note that the jQuery docs say: """ For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead"""

Comment: Thanks @user1.  I'll give you credit if 2 min unless you'd like to be a gentle man and pass on the points to fritzfromlondon.

Comment: @user1.  Any chance you can provide your recommended selector for best performance?  not certain how to combine the [type="checkbox"] selector with the class "cheese_toppings" part.

Comment: @Justin Haha, I can't say I've ever been given the choice on having my answer accepted or not before. I'll say please accept mine, and I gave an upvote to fritzfromlondon (which you can do as well if you haven't already) since his is the same and answered at almost the same time. :)

Comment: @Justin The selector `input[type="checkbox"].cheese_toppings` will give you good performance in any modern browser (which implements querySelectorAll). In older browsers you might get a performance boost by using `$('input.cheese_toppings').filter('[type="checkbox"]')`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('input:checkbox.cheese_toppings').not( checkboxElement ).attr('checked', false)
```

Comment: great answer...  but user1 beat you to it by 10 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

```
//when the page is loaded
$(function() {

//select all checkboxes with class cheese_topping
var allToppingBoxes = $('input[type=checkbox].cheese_topping') 

//when one of these is clicked
allToppingBoxes.click(function() {
  //if the box was unchecked do nothing
  if(!$(this).attr('checked'))
     return;

  //select all except this one that was clicked
  allToppingBoxes.not(this)
    .attr('checked', false); //uncheck all
});

});
```

Also note that you probably want to use jquery prop rather than attr.
You might also want to look at the [:checked pseudoclass](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked) (IE8 down doesn't support it though)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation about prop() vs. attr().  Guess I got some research to do there as well:)

Comment: Honestly, the jquery docs are incredible, you can read through most of them in like 2 hours and they're very easy to read and informative.